# How to change the OSGi Launcher Jar used by the Eclipse OSGi Framework Launcher

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, launcher, equinox

In our project we are using the IBM J9 Java VM and an older version of the Equinox OSGi framework (org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.1.R36x_v20100806.jar). Is it possible to use this combination with the Eclipse OSGi Framework launcher? I tried a view things but could not find a way.

When I start the OSGi framework run configuration and check for the command line that is executed I can see the following:

```
"E:\SVN\trunk3\j9\2.4_ppro11\win32\bin\j9"
"-Dcom.ibm.oti.vm.exe=E:\SVN\trunk3\j9\2.4_ppro11\win32\bin/j9"
"-Djava.home=E:\SVN\trunk3\j9\2.4_ppro11\win32\bin/.."
"-Dcom.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path=E:\SVN\trunk3\j9\2.4_ppro11\win32\bin/"
"-Djava.library.path=E:\SVN\trunk3\j9\2.4_ppro11\win32\bin"
-Xjcl:jclfoun11_24
-Dosgi.noShutdown=true
-Declipse.ignoreApp=true
-Declipse.enableStateSaver=false
-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=javax.*
-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
-classpath E:\Eclipse\eclipse-java-mars-2-win32-x86_64\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main
-dev "file:E:/SVN/trunk3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Internal/dev.properties"
-configuration "file:E:/SVN/trunk3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Internal/"
```

The interesting line is the third one from the end (`-classpath ...`). What you can see is that the launcher executes the Equinox jar from within my Eclipse installation.

Is it possible to change this so that the launcher will execute my OSGi launcher?

e.g.

```
-classpath E:\SVN\trunk3\osgi\org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.1.R36x_v20100806.jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OSGi launcher should also be able to run old Equinox versions. It searches for the `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher` bundle to start the OSGi runtime in these places (in this order):

- the workspace
- the target platform
- among the installed bundles of the running Eclipse instance

If you place a verion of the launcher bundle from Equinox 3.6.1 in your target platform, the framework should just launch.

Comment: I just had to drop org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar into my target platform and it worked - as you said - thanks!